# Grepping all strings on the same line from multiple files

Tags: awk, sed, command-line, grep

Trying to find a way to grep all names on one line for 100 files. grepping all names available in each file must appear on the same line.

FILE1

```
"company":"COMPANY1","companyDisplayName":"CM1","company":"COMPANY2","companyDisplayName":"CM2","company":"COMPANY3","companyDisplayName":"CM3",
```

FILE2

```
"company":"COMPANY99","companyDisplayName":"CM99"
```

The output i actually want is, ( include file name as prefix.)

```
FILE1:COMPANY1,COMPANY2,COMPANY3    
FILE2:COMPANY99
```

i tried `grep -oP '(?<="company":")[^"]*' *` but i get results like this :

```
FILE1:COMPANY1
FILE1:COMPANY2
FILE1:COMPANY3
FILE2:COMPANY99
```

Comment: Each file will only have one line of data?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'[,:]' '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i=="\"company\""){
      val=(val?val OFS:"")$(i+1)
    }
  }
  gsub(/\"/,"",val)
  print FILENAME":"val
  val=""
}
'   Input_file1  Input_file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk -F'[,:]' '                          ##Starting awk program here and setting field separator as colon OR comma here for all lines of Input_file(s).
BEGIN{                                  ##Starting BEGIN section of awk here.
  OFS=","                               ##Setting OFS as comma here.
}                                       ##Closing BEGIN BLOCK here.
{                                       ##Starting main BLOCK here.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                   ##Starting a for loop which starts from i=1 to till value of NF.
    if($i=="\"company\""){              ##Checking condition if field value is equal to "company" then do following.
      val=(val?val OFS:"")$(i+1)        ##Creating a variable named val and concatenating its own value to it each time cursor comes here.
    }                                   ##Closing BLOCK for if condition here.
  }                                     ##Closing BLOCK for, for loop here.
  gsub(/\"/,"",val)                     ##Using gsub to gklobally substitute all " in variable val here.
  print FILENAME":"val                  ##Printing filename colon and variable val here.
  val=""                                ##Nullifying variable val here.
}                                       ##Closing main BLOCK here.
'  Input_file1  Input_file2             ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Input_file1:COMPANY1,COMPANY2,COMPANY3
Input_file2:COMPANY99
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Adding solution in case OP needs to use `grep` and want to get final output from its output(though I will recommend to use `awk` solution itself since we are NOT using multiple commands or sub-shells).

```
grep -oP '(?<="company":")[^"]*' * | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":";OFS=","} prev!=$1 && val{print prev":"val;val=""} {val=(val?val OFS:"")$2;prev=$1} END{if(val){print prev":"val}}'
```

Comment: @Alpha.Mc, Could you please check this answer once and let me know if this helps you?

Answer (score 0):

There are two tools that can take the output of your grep command and reformat it the way you want. First tool is [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/). Second is [tsv-summarize](https://ebay.github.io/tsv-utils/docs/tool_reference/tsv-summarize.html) from eBay's [tsv-utils](https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils) package (disclaimer: I'm the author). Both tools solve this in similar ways:

```
$ # The grep output
$ echo $'FILE1:COMPANY1\nFILE1:COMPANY2\nFILE1:COMPANY3\nFILE2:COMPANY99' > grep-output.txt
$ cat grep-output.txt
FILE1:COMPANY1
FILE1:COMPANY2
FILE1:COMPANY3
FILE2:COMPANY99

$ # Using GNU datamash
$ cat grep-output.txt | datamash -field-separator : --group 1 unique 2
FILE1:COMPANY1,COMPANY2,COMPANY3
FILE2:COMPANY99

$ # Using tsv-summarize
$ cat grep-output.txt | tsv-summarize --delimiter : --group-by 1 --unique-values 2 --values-delimiter ,
FILE1:COMPANY1,COMPANY2,COMPANY3
FILE2:COMPANY99
```